# Office 2013: Word background image as a style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

I'm currently creating a whole style for document which I will write.
But now it's so that when I start a chapter, on that page (and only that page or other pages containing a chapter - as defined by a style) will add a background image just on top of the page.

Is there any way on how I can embed that in a my Word style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same header footer across the whole document (or don't make use of the header and footer at all) then you can add your image to the first page header footer. Then with each chapter add a section break and make sure that the headers and footers are linked and the image will repeat on these pages.

Both options can be found by double clicking on the header and footer:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some guidance in how to that. I don't know how to link headers and footers. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, I've added an image to help make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is what I need however, I still have a small problem. When I select my style, it adds a page break by default (I've added this), but the link to previous and different first page only works after a section break, so is there a way to add a section break before a style?

Comment: Yes that is a limitation. You can work around this by instead of styling a paragraph with heading 1, instead create a new AutoText entry with a heading 1 paragraph and a section break and insert that for each new chapter. Not perfect, but I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

This way may help you, create a picture fit your word page size (example A4), decorated top of picture as style you expected. Then use `Watermark` feature to embedded the picture as word document's background image.

Comment: But this will make the image to apply on all the pages? I would like if I select a specific style that my text is formatted at a specific font (no problem) and add an image on top of that page...